# Is there a more concise way to define this simple hat function?

Tags: python, numpy

I am studying Fourier series and want to plot some of the results in Python. One common function to analyze using Fourier series is the hat function:

[image: example plot here]

The code below shows two different ways that I've coded the hat function. One uses `numpy`, the other uses a custom function `hat(x,a,L)` that I wrote. The parameter `a` represents the width of the hat, while `L` is the overall domain of the function from (-L,L).

I think that the function I wrote is more readable, but I doubt it's as fast as the numpy `piecewise` function. But I think the numpy function is pretty ugly.

Is there a better way to write the hat function that is more concise and fast? (Bonus points for readability)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# defining the hat function parameters, domain
L=-5
a=1
x=np.linspace(-L,L,100)

# using my hat function
y=hat(x,a,L)
plt.plot(x,y,'r')
plt.show()

# numpy hat function - piecewise
y=np.piecewise(x,
               [x<-a,(-a<x)&(x<0),x==0,(0<x)&(x<a),a<x],
               [0,lambda x:1+x/a,1,lambda x:1-x/a,0])
plt.plot(x,y,'r')
plt.show()

# hat function
def hat(x,a,L):
    y=x.copy()
    y[x<-a]=0
    y[(x>-a)&(x<0)]=1+x[(x>-a)&(x<0)]/a
    y[x==0]=1
    y[(x>0)&(x<a)]=1-x[(x>0)&(x<a)]/a
    y[x>a]=0
    return y
```

Comment: You have 3 redundant conditions in the implementations. `y = np.select([(-a<x) & (x<=0), (0<x) & (x<a)], [1+x, 1-x], 0)` does the same with two conditions. Whether this is more readable is based on opinion.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSzczesny. I'll use that. I guess I should have asked for the most concise solution -- then my question wouldn't have been closed and I could select your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution

```
def hat(x,a,L):
    y=x.copy()
    y[(x<-a) | (x>a)]=0
    y[(x>-a)&(x<0)]+=1
    y[x==a]=1
    y[(x>0)&(x<a)]*=-1
    y[(x>0)&(x<a)]+=1
    return y
```

in your `hat` function, you have `y[x==a]=1` but in the numpy version you have  `,x==0,` = `,1,`, which are not the same.

### _______

Something like this with symmetry

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# defining the hat function parameters, domain
L=5
a=1
x=np.linspace(0,L,51)
# hat function
def hat(x,a,L):
    y=x.copy()
    y[x==0]=1
    y[(x > 0) & (x < a)] *= -1
    y[(x > 0) & (x < a)] += 1
    y[(x>=a)]=0
    y = np.hstack((y[-1:0:-1], y))
    return y
# using my hat function
y2=hat(x,a,L)

x=np.linspace(-L,L,101)
# numpy hat function - piecewise
y=np.piecewise(x,
               [x<-a,(-a<x)&(x<0),x==0,(0<x)&(x<a),a<x],
               [0,lambda x:1+x,1,lambda x:1-x,0])
plt.plot(x,y,'b')
plt.plot(x,y2,'r')
plt.show()
```

### ____

you could also use math to compute the y signal and then put some zeros

```
x=np.linspace(-L,L,101)
y3 = np.zeros(x.shape)
y3[(x>-a)&(x<a)] = -np.abs(x[(x>-a)&(x<a)]) + 1
```

but it really depend on your case

Comment: You're correct, that was a typo. It should have been `y[x==0]=1` in both cases

Comment: Your function is probably faster than my function, but it somewhat obscures the mathematical definition of the hat function, which I would say is more clear in my function. I guess we can't have it all :(

Comment: Your function seems symmetrical so you can also create half of it and then copy by symmetry to get it entirely